# Execute code before breakpoint in Netbeans

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, netbeans-platform

Is it possible in Netbeans to start your program from the middle (breakpoint) BUT
make sure that all code before that breakpoint is already in the memory ?

Otherwise all the variables before my breakpoint will not exist,
and I hate it to keep starting from the top pressing F7 for 10min.

Fosa

Comment: Why did you do that? Normally, program will run from begining to breaking points. You do not need press F7 like that. http://cobweb.cs.uga.edu/~shoulami/sp2009/cs1301/tutorial/NetBeansDebuggerTutorial/NetBeansDebuggerTutorial.htm

Comment: Ok I found It! Thank you so much @NguyenDoanTung